# Specify possible values on groupby - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which changes according to an user input. I am grouping according to two different columns: a date and another one which can only take two values, let's call it 'boolean column'.

```
data = df.loc[:,['date1', 'date2', 'id']]
mask = (data['date1'] - data['date2']) < timedelta(days=1)
boolean_dictionary = {True: 'Value 1', False: 'Value 2'}
data['boolean column'] = mask.replace(boolean_dictionary)
data['date2'] = data['date2'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
data = df.groupby(['date2', 'boolean column'])['id'].count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

With this code I can get what I want easily. This is an example of an output:

```
date2           boolean column   
2020-09         Value 1         1
                Value 2         0
2020-10         Value 1         3
                Value 2         0
2020-11         Value 1        24
                Value 2         4
2020-12         Value 1       142
                Value 2       230
```

However, I have a problem when the user introduces a filter which returns entries of only one of the possible categories (Value 1/ Value 2). Here you are an example:

```
date2           boolean column
2020-09-22      Value 1         1
```

In this case, as my "boolean column" only has values of type "Value 1", the `.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()` is not doing the trick to add the "Value 2" index with a 0 value.

This is what I would like to get:

```
date2           boolean column
2020-09-22      Value 1         1
                Value 2         0
```

Is there a way to tell the `groupby` method that my "boolean column" has two possible values instead of only one? Otherwise, what would be the best way of getting the output I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo ucan convert `boolean column` to categoricals with specify  all categories (tested in pandas 1.2.1):

```
print (df)
        date2 boolean column   id
0  2020-09-22        Value 1  aaa

df['boolean column'] = pd.Categorical(df['boolean column'],categories=['Value 1','Value 2'])
```

Then `count` add `0` for missing values:

```
data = df.groupby(['date2', 'boolean column'])['id'].count()
print (data)
date2       boolean column
2020-09-22  Value 1           1
            Value 2           0
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed, and you discovered me a new pandas class which seems to be quite useful. I will read more about it.